# Unity Android READ_PHONE_STATE permission

Tags: android, admob, chartboost

I've created a mobile game for iOS and Android that uses chartboost plugin to show advertisement and AdMob as well.

The thing is that I've created some permissions in the AndroidManifest in order to make this plugins work and one of this permissions is `READ_PHONE_STATE` which is asking for permission to read the call information to those who install the game. I don't like this because could generate distrust among users.

I've tried to delete the line that asks for this permission but when I do it the game crashes at the beginning, so, is there any way to remove this permission? Or do I have to keep it if I want to show advertisement?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the chartboost plugin but I have created my own AdMob plugin and the only permissions that are required in the AndroidManifest file are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

This is when using Google Play services rather than the AdMob SDK.